# overriding the browser's CTRL+F and replace it with Silverlight custom search

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Can anyone help me in Overriding the browser's CTRL+F and replace it with Silverlight Custom-search. I guess we can have JavaScript to handle this case.

Comment: 1. Make sure you capture the "event" of ctrl-F in the browser. 2. Call your Silverlight script. 3. Search in Silverlight. You are allowed to do some work before going here. (And you are allowed to ask us to help you when you get stuck. Asking us to do your work is an entirely different thing.)

Comment: I don't think he was asking us to do it for him, "help me in doing X" can easily mean "tell me where to start".  Also your comment doesn't explain _how_ to capture the CTRL+F event in the browser, which is what I came here for from google.  Unhelpful :(

Comment: You can examine codes from other sources like codepen.io for the search function and add it into a key override event like in my answer below!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, to replace the Find function:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress",function (event) { /* Add keydown too */
    if ((event.keyCode == 114) || (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 70)) { 
    // Block CTRL + F event
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Comment: To work on Apple or not `const isCtrlKey = navigator.platform.indexOf('Mac') > -1 ? event.metaKey : event.ctrlKey`

Answer (score 0):

I have made a keyboard shortcut for this on my website, i have also created this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13otmc0f/3/) With the script on it and a working demo below this post! The demo is the exact same as in the fiddle! Also For reference the source for my site url as seen in snippet is [This Link](https://antimalwareprogram.co/view-source:antimalwareprogram.co-pages_php.source-javascript_page.js)
And My other stack overflow post, very different from this one by the way, is [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997901/override-browsers-search-feature-ctrlf-but-reuse-its-native-search-field/45624477#45624477) And the shortcut.js fiddle is [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/hpupapha/)

```html
<h1> Click In This Box and press ctrl+F </h1>

  <a href https://antimalwareprogram.co/view-source:antimalwareprogram.co-pages_php.source-javascript_page.js tagret=blank>Click to see my site source if this fiddle is broken!</a> <p>
 <b></b>This is The Url: https://antimalwareprogram.co/view-source:antimalwareprogram.co-pages_php.source-javascript_page.js<b></b></p>
  <h1>
  Then Scroll down to the bottom then scroll up, or do ctrl+F there and inser this line: https://antimalwareprogram.co/shortcuts.js<h1>
 <h4>
 that and everything below it is part of my keyboard shortcuts</h4>
<h1>
The entire code is on the js panel</h1>
<hr>
<--The Javascript-->


<script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/shortcuts.js"> </script> <!-- Or Just open that script page and ctrl+A Then Ctrl+C and past it into your own site and change url to /filename.js -must save it as a .js extension!  This script searches my site! To make it search your just change down below where it says  --- 
document.writeln(" <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"domains\" value=\"https://antimalwareprogram.co\" checked=\"checked\"> "); 
document.writeln("     <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sitesearch\" value=\"https://antimalwareprogram.co\" checked=\"checked\"> ");

Just change the https://antimalwareprogram.co on both lines to https://yoursite or http://yoursite make sure not to remove the other slashes around it though or the script wont work, also this wont work if you have a script blocker blocker , so you can have a html meta no script redirect tag but nothing else will work if its not that meta tag for noscript! -->

<script>
 shortcut.add("Ctrl+F",function() { 
 


document.writeln(" <link href=\"https://docs.google.com/static/document/client/css/3164405079-KixCss_ltr.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> ");
document.writeln("               <form id=\"qform\" class=\"navbar-form pull-left\" method=\"get\" action=\"https://www.google.com/search\" role=\"search\"> "); 
document.writeln("  ");
document.writeln("  ");

document.writeln(" <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"domains\" value=\"https://antimalwareprogram.co\" checked=\"checked\"> "); 
document.writeln("     <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sitesearch\" value=\"https://antimalwareprogram.co\" checked=\"checked\"> ");

document.writeln(" <div id=\"docs-findbar-id\" class=\"docs-ui-unprintable\"name=\"q\" type=\"submit\"><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog-wrapper\"><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog-holder\"><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog\" role=\"dialog\" tabindex=\"0\" style=\"margin-top: 0px;\"><div id=\"docs-slidingdialog-content\" class=\"docs-slidingdialog-content goog-inline-block\"><div class=\"docs-findbar-content\"><div id=\"docs-findbar-spinner\" style=\"display: none;\"><div class=\"docs-loading-animation\"><div class=\"docs-loading-animation-dot-1\"></div><div class=\"docs-loading-animation-dot-2\"></div><div class=\"docs-loading-animation-dot-3\"></div></div></div><div id=\"docs-findbar-input\" class=\"docs-findbar-input goog-inline-block\"><table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"docs-findinput-container\"><tbody><tr><td class=\"docs-findinput-input-container\"><input aria-label=\"Find in document\" autocomplete=\"on\" type=\"text\" class=\"docs-findinput-input\" name=\"q\" type=\"submit\"  placeholder=\"Search Our Site\"></td><td class=\"docs-findinput-count-container\"><span class=\"docs-findinput-count\" role=\"region\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\"></span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class=\"docs-offscreen\" id=\"docs-findbar-input-context\">Context:<div class=\"docs-textcontextcomponent-container\"></div></div><div role=\"button\" id=\"docs-findbar-button-previous\" class=\"goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard jfk-button-narrow jfk-button-collapse-left jfk-button-collapse-right jfk-button-disabled\" aria-label=\"Previous\" aria-disabled=\"true\" style=\"user-select: none;\"><div class=\"docs-icon goog-inline-block \"><div class=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</div></div></div><div role=\"button\" id=\"docs-findbar-button-next\" class=\"goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard jfk-button-narrow jfk-button-collapse-left jfk-button-disabled\" aria-label=\"Next\" aria-disabled=\"true\" style=\"user-select: none;\"><div class=\"docs-icon goog-inline-block \"><div class=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</div></div></div><div role=\"button\" id=\"\" class=\"goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard jfk-button-narrow\" tabindex=\"0\" data-tooltip=\"More options\" aria-label=\"\" style=\"user-select: none;\"><div class=\"docs-icon goog-inline-block \"><div class=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</div></div></div></div></div><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog-close-container goog-inline-block\"><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog-button-close goog-flat-button goog-inline-block\" aria-label=\"Close\" role=\"button\" aria-disabled=\"false\" tabindex=\"0\" style=\"user-select: none;\"><div class=\"goog-flat-button-outer-box goog-inline-block\"><div class=\"goog-flat-button-inner-box goog-inline-block\"><div class=\"docs-icon goog-inline-block \"><div class=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div tabindex=\"0\" style=\"position: absolute;\"></div></div></div></div> ");
document.writeln(" <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"window.location.reload();return false;\"></a> "); 
document.writeln("  ");
document.writeln("                </form> "); 
document.writeln("  ");
document.writeln(" <h1> Press esc key to cancel searching!</h1> ");
 
shortcut.add("Ctrl+F",function() {
 alert("Already Searching! Press the esc key to stop searching!");
});
  shortcut.add("esc",function() {

  location.reload();

  
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

a little addition to Randiel's answer
(sorry I can't add comments)
you can try with event keydown instead of keypress if keypress doesn't work for you.
it works for me.