# Override browser's search feature (CTRL+F), but reuse its native search field

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, user-experience

I would like to **override** CTRL+F in order to provide a custom search feature on a HTML page. This can easily be done with :

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 70) {
        event.preventDefault();          
        my_own_search();
    } }
```

but then I won't be able to use the browser's bottom native **search field** (example here with Firefox, French language) :

[image: Description]

**How to do a custom search feature that reuses the browser's native bottam search textbox ?**

**If not possible, what do you suggest for creating a custom textbox sticked at the top right (like the Search bar in Chrome) or bottom (like the Search bar in Firefox), with Bootstrap for example ?**

---

*Another example : the **PDF viewer** in Chrome provides custom search (=not the regular search on HTML pages, but a search adapted for PDF documents)  but with the browser's native search field:*

[image]

Comment: Only with a browser plugin, and even so it's not completely trivial.

Comment: Please add a comment for downvote ;) Why is this question not interesting ?

Comment: I would think very hard about what benefit you are adding for the user before overriding default behavior like this. If a website overrode Ctrl + F, they better have an amazing find experience that's light-years beyond the browser's default, or I'm going to immediately leave the site... Just sayin'.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The document I'm displaying is not a standard 2D "page" with text and standard layout (with a beginning on top, and an end on bottom). It is totally different. That's why browser's "standard search" is useless.

Answer (score 5):

You should NEVER be able to override a browser feature from a website.  If you can, it's a major security fault in the browser.

As has been mentioned, plugins can be written for individual browsers, but they must be installed by the user (i.e. they are giving permission for your override).  Otherwise you're out of luck

Answer (score 5):

I suppose because this is an old thread, but the correct answer marked here is now invalid. I have seen this on two sites in the past two days, and I kind of love it. Codepen.io for one:

Command/Control+F when in the first pane, and you will see their custom search.

If you examine their code you can see they have custom events for it, do a 'Search All Files' in chrome dev tools (CDT) for ***CodeMirror-search-field***

Comment: Thanks @webdevinci. My website http://bigpicture.bi/demo now has custom search feature with CTRL+F.

Comment: And you're upvote allows gets me a couple points closer to being able to reply on posts that aren't mine! so thanks for that. And I just started seeing this everywhere, loving it, and have huge ideas for site navigation (not just finding text, but navigating site, etc).

Comment: @Basj , just getting back to this, do you mind checking this as accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

To override the search field you need to use JavaScript keycodes, using arrays like this:

```
// 74=j, 75=k, 78=n, 84=t,27=esc, 17=ctrl
var forbiddenCtrlKeys = new Array(74, 75, 78, 84, 123, 91, 92, 44, 165, 18, 122, 78, 27, 17, 16);
// 37=left_arrow, 39=right_arrow
var forbiddenAltKeys = new Array(37, 39, 27, 123, 91, 92, 44, 165, 18, 122, 78, 27, 17, 16);
// 8=backspace, 116=F5
var forbiddenSingleKeys = new Array(8, 116, 123, 91, 92, 44, 165, 18, 122, 78, 27, 17, 16);
// per le textbox 116=F5
var forbiddenTextBoxKeys = new Array(116, 27, 123, 91, 92, 44, 165, 18, 122, 78, 27, 17, 16);

key = window.event.keyCode; // IE

if (window.event.ctrlKey) { // CTRL
  isCtrl = true;
  isAlt = false
}
```

Swap the keycodes with the ones you want disabled.

A full list of keycodes can be found **[here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)**.